# Spring Boot 1.4 and Thymeleaf 2 Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm trying Spring Boot 1.4 and Thymeleaf 2. I want to secure my application. This is my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/resources/static/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

This is my MVC controller:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/index").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }    
}
```

However when I try to access `localhost:8080` it shows index page without css, js! When I manually login via `localhost:8080/login.html` everything works OK. I obey the convention of Spring - Thymeleaf integration and static resources are under `/resources/static` and templates under `/resource/templates`.

What is the missing point for me?

**EDIT:**

It works with this way:

```
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
```

However, should I add all the folders under static resources with this way? It seems I miss something.

Comment: It's strange, but it works without further configuration when you put your css and js files in `src/main/resources/static/resources`

Answer (score 1):

You should add css and javascript files to `src/main/webapp`

Now given your structure is as follows:

```
webapp
|__css/myStyles.css
|__js/myjs.js
|__images/myImage.gif
|__WEB-INF
```

Add this to your security configuration

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity security) {
    security.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/libs/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
}
```

Comment: Should I add all the folders one by one? I think I could use a wildcard since putting static files under `resources` folder is the convention for spring-thymeleaf.

Comment: if you create a resources folder under webapps and add all these folders inside them then just adding "/recources/**"  in antMatchers should also work.

Comment: No, it should not. Resources are accessed via `/css`, `/js` etc. when you access from UI even they are places under resources. Spring intercepts according to computed URLs (they are not accessed via path of `/static` even they are under that folder. It's been hided when you run UI).

Comment: Hmm, will have to test.